# How do I eliminate line break from fgets function in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, fgets

I am attempting to make a gallery that calls the image names from a flat file database using the PHP 'fgets' function. There are different sections in the gallery, each with it's own default image, and a small list of images that the users can select from. Everything is working fine, except for one button.

I have one button on the page that is supposed to reset all the galleries to their default images using Javascript OnClick. It works exactly as I want it to, with one small hitch: It copies the line break at the end of the line allong with the characters on the line, breaking the Javascript.

The offending code:

```
function back(){
document.getElementById('back').className='back';
document.getElementById('one').className='cellcont';

//This should output the proper javascript, but does not
<?php
$a = fopen('c.txt','r');
if (!$a) {echo 'ERROR: Unable to open file.'; exit;}
$b = fgets($a);
echo "document.getElementById('i1').src='$b';";
fclose($a);
?>

}
```

How it outputs:

```
function back(){
document.getElementById('back').className='back';
document.getElementById('one').className='cellcont';
document.getElementById('i1').src='00.jpg
';}
```

As you can see, the ending quotation mark and the semi-colon falls on the next line, and this breaks the button.

With the files I'm using now, I can get around this problem by changing, "fgets($a)" to, "fgets($a, 7)" but I need to have it grab the entire line so that if the client decides to enter a file with a longer name, it does not break the gallery on them.

Comment: Since it's a string, you're just trying to remove whitespace (linebreak) characters in a string. Lots of answers around here for that, I imagine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the php trim() function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$b = trim(fgets($a));
```

Comment: be careful, it will also remove some other characters such as spaces that may be part of the actual file content you want to read.

Comment: This is sort of wrong. The answer by @ariel should be the accepted one as it will only remove the trailing new line, and not all whitespace at both ends of the line.

Comment: In context of the entire question this is correct. If your input requires to preserve trailing white space then you need a stricter use of trim, but when you are getting a list of URLs you do not want the extra space.

Answer (score 40):

Use `rtrim()`.

Specifically:

```
rtrim($var, "\r\n");
```

(To avoid trimming other characters, pass in just newline.)

Comment: If you have to handle files with fixed-length records and trailing spaces, this answer is the one. The function provided by @Alex Kennberg, even though correct for the current question, was exactly the reason for a bug I just fixed.

Comment: A weird thing with this function: usually PHP reads either " " or ' ' as a string. I generally use ' '. However, you must use quotes " " for this function.

I guess in this case PHP decides to read ' ' as a single character instead of as a string.

Tested on a local Windows server.

Answer (score -1):

```
$b = fgets($a);
$b = preg_replace("/[\n|\r]/",'',$b);
```

Comment: You should not use a regex for this. Use `str_replace()`, it will be much faster. But even better is to use `rtrim()`

Comment: It removes the pipes too.